# why do i get Unexpected token ':' at arrays

Tags: node.js, typescript

Whenever I try to create an array in typescript and assign a type to it I get the following error:

```
let array:[string]=["123"]
         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

Examples where I get it:

```
let array:[string]=["123"]
let array:string[]=["test"]
let array:any[]=[]
let array:number[]=[1,2]
```

I don't really understand why this is the case.

I'm expecting that the array can just be created with the type.
I tried every case described above.

Comment: please share reproducible example  via TypeScript playground

Answer (score 3):

The most probable reason is that you try running directly your TypeScript file with JavaScript runtime engine. Colon `:` is not legal (syntax error) in JavaScript after a variable name.

You must *transpile* your `.ts` file first into a plain `.js` file.

See e.g. the TypeScript get started: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-tooling-in-5-minutes.html#compiling-your-code